# How to represent a pattern within a Rectangle's area

Tags: c#, arrays, rectangles

The goal is to have an object that represents a 2D collection of Boolean values.

[image: Grid Problem]

I have a point grid of Size(x, y)

Objects are placed on the grid at location Point(x, y) with bounds Rectangle(new Size(w, h), new Point(x, y))

The goal is to represent the object as a bool[,] where the index of the array location represent the offset in the Rectangles bounds.

I may be over thinking this a bit, so I'll explain that I used Rectangle because of the very handy IntersectsWith.

The objects will be allowed to move one unit in any direction, but they are not allowed to move to a location already occupied by another object.

I would like the end usage to be something like:

```
Pattern p1 = new Pattern(Point location1, bool[,] pattern);
Pattern p2 = new Pattern(Point location2, bool[,] pattern);

if(p1.Intersects(p2))
  throw new ...
```

I only care of the patterns overlap. I'd like the general size and shape of the pattern to be mutable.

I'm trying to think of a way to redefine the pattern with certain rules based on total area.

I'm looking for advice on the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe this question fit better on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does your problem have a visual representation or are you using only the concept of Rectangle?

Comment: So if the Rectangles intersect, then the shapes **may** intersect.  The Rectangle approach is a good way to quickly determine if you need to inspect further.  For a final determination, you'll have to iterate over the arrays and see if any of the same locations within are both set to true.  Obviously you'll need to explicitly check to make sure you don't exceed the rows/cols of the other shape if the two patterns have different sized "bounding rectangles".

Comment: You may be interested in this [Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpjhEedIN1E) I created awhile back (source code links in the comments down below).  I represented the pieces as a Location with a List of Offsets for each part of the pattern.  Don't know if it was the best design, but it suited my needs well.

Comment: Idle_Mind - Very nice app, well done! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try  a treemap. Sort the rectangles and put the first into a 2d tree.
 Split the tree on both axis and put the next rectangle where it fit. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with a simple list of Points. I feel I may have been over thinking it too much. Each object has a list of points, a method for determining if a newly added point is a neighbor of an existing point, and a method for determining if a point is owned by the object.

It's a quasi mediator pattern, the root object contains a list of many sub objects, the sub objects query the root object for availability of points, the root object queries all sub objects.

This should, some what, help maintain the SOLID/SRP.